# Problems with shared buffer and synchronized programming

Tags: c, pthreads, buffer, mutex

I just started learning how to mess with threads and synchronized programming in C. I'm trying to code a reader which uses threads (POSIX interface) to read selected files from a shared buffer. The children threads will retrieve the file names from the buffer, while the father thread will be infinitly reading filenames from stdin and placing them in the buffer. What am I doing wrong?

```
pthread_mutex_t lock;

static char* files[NFILES];
int top = NFILES-1;

void putInBuffer(char* file){
    pthread_mutex_lock(&lock);
    if(top < NFILES-1){
        files[top] = file;
        top++;
    }
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&lock);
}

char* removeFromBuffer(){
    char* file;
    pthread_mutex_lock(&lock);
    file = files[top];
    top--;
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&lock);
    return file;
}

void* leitor(){
    int op,i,r,cl;
    char* file;
    char buff[NCHARS];
    char teste[NCHARS];
    while(1){
        pthread_mutex_lock(&lock);
        file = removeFromBuffer();
        printf("%s\n", file);
        op = open(file, O_RDONLY);
        if(op == -1) {
            perror("Open unsuccessful");
            pthread_exit((void*)-1);
        }
        r = read(op, teste, NBYTES);
        if(r == -1){
            perror("Read unsuccessful");
            pthread_exit((void*)-1);
        }
        for(i=0; i<NLINES-1; i++){
         r = read(op, buff, NBYTES);
         if(r == -1){
            perror("Read unsuccessful");
            pthread_exit((void*)-1);
         }
         if(strcmp(buff,teste) != 0){
          perror("Incorrect file");
          pthread_exit((void*)-1);
         }
        }
        cl = close (op);
        if(cl == -1){
            perror("Close unsuccessful");
            pthread_exit((void*)-1);
        }
        printf("Correct file: %s\n", file);
        pthread_mutex_unlock(&lock);
    }
    pthread_exit((void*)0);
    return NULL;
}

int main(){

    pthread_t threads[NTHREADS];
    int i,*status;
    char file[LENFILENAME];
    if (pthread_mutex_init(&lock, NULL))
    {
        perror("\n mutex init failed\n");
        exit(-1);
    }
    for(i=0;i<NTHREADS;i++){
        if(pthread_create(&(threads[i]),NULL, leitor,NULL)){
            perror("Failed to create thread");
            exit(-1);
        }
    }

    while(1){
        read(STDIN_FILENO, file, LENFILENAME);
        printf("%s\n", file);
        putInBuffer(file);
        printf("%s\n", removeFromBuffer());
    }
    for (i=0;i<NTHREADS;i++){
        if(pthread_join(threads[i],(void**)&status)){
            perror("Failed to join thread");
            exit(-1);
        }
        printf("Thread returned %d\n", status);
    }
    pthread_mutex_destroy(&lock);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given what your program is doing, it seems that you should use a separate semaphore for notifying the child threads of new input instead of using the mutex that you have created.

Each child thread should wait on the semaphore at the top of the `while` loop, where you currently have `pthread_mutex_lock()`.  After the parent has finished `putInBuffer`, it should release the semaphore once.  When a child thread grabs the semaphore, it can call `removeFromBuffer` to get the next file, and read it (i.e. what you have already written).  After the child finishes with the file, it should not release the semaphore, just go back to the top of the loop and wait on it again.

You have correctly used the mutex in `putInBuffer` and `removeFromBuffer` to protect accesses to the shared variables `files` and `top`.